# css horizontal scrolling menu with dropdowns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am having dropdowns in a menu that has horizontal scrolling on mobile resolution.

As you can see in the example the desktop version is able to display the dropdowns when the menu is hovered, however, when using the mobile version that uses `overflow-y: hidden` the dropdown is obscured.

I have attempted to change the `overflow-y` to all available options, I would have thought setting it to `visible` would allow the dropdown to be seen however, this is not the case.

I'm open to anything at this point, I'm about to use position fixed and set it with javascript but I would prefer not to if there is a better solution in css.

I need to leave the horizontal scrolling of the top level menu items.

Thanks for any help.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main.mobile {
  max-width: 250px;
}

.main {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
}

.mobile .nav {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list__item {
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  position: relative;
  transition: .2s all;
}

.list__item:hover {
  background: #dc205c; 
}

.list__item:hover .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s all;
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
}

.dropdown__item {
  padding: 1em;
  transition: .2s all;
}

.dropdown__item:hover {
  background: #dc205c;
}
```

```html
<main class="main mobile">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>item 1</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>longer item 2</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>item 3</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>item 4</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</main>

<main class="main">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>item 1</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>longer item 2</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>item 3</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <span>item 4</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</main>
```

Comment: When using `overflow-x: scroll`, your `overflow-y: visible` wil automatically be set to `auto`. so you will have to solve this using javascript.
try looking at these pages:
https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/
https://jsfiddle.net/68fBE/2/